# conditional apache lockdown using .htaccess

Tags: facebook, .htaccess

How can allow Facebook access to my test domain for Facebook connecting while at the same time having the domain locked down to every other HTTP client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent ^FaceBook/2\.0 let_me_in
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=let_me_in
```